# Django Template tag 'with' not working as expected

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to use Django Template 'with' tag to alternate between two icons, the solid icon represents liked posts (called chirps in this project), and the regular icon represent non-liked posts(chirps).

After some iterations this is the code I'm trying to implement but for some reason the last conditional 'if' always interpret the variable 'blahblah' as False, even when has been reassigned to True:

```
<span style="float: right">
 {% with blahblah=False %}
   {% for like in likes %}
      {% if like.userId == currentUserId and chirp == like.chirpId %}
         {% with blahblah=True %}
         <i id="like{{ chirp.id }}" class="fa-solid fa-heart likeBttn"></i> 
         {% endwith %}
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   {% if not blahblah %}
    <i id="like{{ chirp.id }}" class="fa-regular fa-heart likeBttn"></i>
   {% endif %}
   &nbsp; <span class="count{{chirp.id}}">{{liked}}{{ chirp.numLikes }}</span> likes
 {% endwith %}
</span>
```

I have tried to use {% empty %} tag but doesn't really apply this problem because 'likes' is never empty. This is the simplest implementation to the problem but unfortunately is not working.

Answer (score 0):

After you reach `{% endwith %}` then anything that `{% with %}` changed is not available. It's not clean Python, so do not treat it that way. Try to not use Python's logic in templates unless it's really necessary.

Comment: Got it. So, basically is not possible to replicate with Django templates?

Comment: Some things are possible, but before you use them, you need to fully understand basics. You can do some Pythonic stuff with custom template tags: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/